# How to loop through all image files (png) in a directory and send to deepstack?

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a script that will look at a directory and send all of the files of a certain type (PNG) to my Deepstack face recognition.  The python script is Deepstack shows (and works fine) is as follows:

```
import requests

user_image = open("image1.png","rb").read()

response = requests.post("http://localhost:80/v1/vision/face/register",
files={"image":user_image},data={"userid":"User Name"}).json()

print(response)
```

Comment: Have  you tried using `os.listdir()` ?

Comment: Are you asking how to list files in a directory? How to identify the "png" extension?

Comment: Try using `glob` module in python. You can filter files based on anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking how to check all the files in a directory and operate only on the files ending in ".png".

To do that, you would want to use the `os.listdir` function to provide a list of all files in a given directory, then check if each one ends in ".png" using a substring.

For example:

```
import os
# this will list the contents of the current directory by default 
# you can also give os.listdir an argument with a path to a specific directory to list
fileList = os.listdir()
for fileName in contents:
    if fileName[-4:] == ".png":
        ### your code goes here, using fileName
```

This example isn't perfect because it throws an error for filenames with fewer than 4 characters, but you can get the idea.

Comment: [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) would be the preferable way to get a file's extension regardless of its length.

Comment: *filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(directory_of_your_file)*

can be used to get the extension of the file directory passed as the parameter. This will split the directory and return the file_name and file_extension separately. This will be more efficient as the extension of a file might not always be of 4 characters (.ai files for example).